# How to increase the width and height of the child component specific element equal to the parent component in Angular 12 and Typescript?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have included the child component in parent component. and I displaying that child component within col-md-8. What I need is, I have to highlight the child component's particular div with some extra text to equal to parent component. Like I added that image below.

[layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgln6.png)

In this image. You can see that, child component's layout. That green box width and height should be like that. I don't know how to do this. any suggestion?

I tried to change the css using @Input() @HostBinding decorators. but it is only change the inside of the child element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use template reference variables in the way

```
<child-left #childLeft></child-left>
<child-content [style.height.px]="childLeft?.offsetHeight">
</child-content>
```

But really I don't understand so much your image :(